# May I change my Android keystore for security reasons?

Tags: java, android, keystore

Three years ago I made my first Android application and signed it with my keystore and uploaded on playstore.

Well that time I shared my keystore with my college friends
Now I made a update for my application and I want to make it secure so no one other than me can place a update or cannot do anything wrong with my work. Well that app is published using my college account so anyone can access that account. They can't delete  (college rules) but still they can experiment on my application.

Is changing the keystore password will help? Anything I can do in this situation? I have my original key with me. If there is no way to make it secure then definitely I don't want to waste my time on updating.

Comment: You can change you key store password.please go through the link  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Changing the password is not problem... I want to know if changing the password will help me in my situation and how it will be secure

Comment: Thanks this helped... So conclusion is if someone else have keystore file then he can update my application... Definitely now I'll not update my app

Comment: Yes something like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change keystore of a application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382236/how-to-change-keystore-of-a-application-in-android)

Comment: Also a potential duplicate [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357909/anyway-to-change-keystore-or-keystores-info-on-android-without-publish-new-app). Please don't add declarations in your question as to whether something is a duplicate or not - someone may well find things you have not. Just let someone suggest duplicates in the normal fashion, and discuss their validity in the comments as necessary.

Comment: The duplicates were found [using this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=android+change+keystore).

Comment: You may be right, but would you explain _how_ it's not a duplicate? The answer seem to be that if you wish to re-publish the same app, you must use the same keystore. Thus, if you wish to use a different keystore in order to invalidate an existing one, it seems the other questions are saying that you must publish a new application. Are they not saying that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change your keystore. Each app is linked to one.